# How can I get and compare two XML attributes using TSQL where the XML string is stored in a field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sqlxml

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Imagine a table:

```
id | contentXml
1  | <node attr1='a' attr2='b' attr3='a'/>
2  | <node attr1='a' attr2='b' attr3='c'/>
3  | <node attr3='c' attr2='d' attr1='c'/>
```

The expected result should be a list of ID's where the value of attr1 and attr3 are the same. 
Note that the order of the attributes may be different like in the example above.

Result: 1 and 3

Comment: Have you tried something? Show some code.

Comment: Sorry, I really haven't tried something as I'm clueless on how am I going to interpret an XML in a field via TSQL, hence my question. I didn't know that there's like an XPath thing for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think fastest way would be to use [sqlxml exist()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method:

```
select
    t.id
from Table1 as t
where t.contentXml.exist('node[@attr1 = @attr3]') = 1
```

It's also possible to do this with [sqlxml value()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx):

```
select
    t.id
from Table1 as t
where
    t.contentXml.value('(node/@attr1)[1]', 'varchar(max)') =
    t.contentXml.value('(node/@attr3)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
```

But this one would be slower.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9bf1/8)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a different approach:

```
SELECT id, 
       t.contentXml.value('(/node/@attr1)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
       t.contentXml.value('(/node/@attr3)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM Table1 t
WHERE t.contentXml.value('(/node/@attr1)[1]','nvarchar(max)') = t.contentXml.value('(/node/@attr3)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

And working sql code on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab4a7)

Result:

```
id
1   a   a
3   c   c
```

Comment: Yes, is not different. When I was answering you just had the first suggestion using `exist` method. Once I answered, with a difference of seconds you edited your answer and added the second approach. I guess you where adding the second option same time I was adding my answer. That is why I added the comment "Here you have a different approach". Oopss...you deleted your comment.